# I have a 2019 CX3 that pulls 1.5 amps with all off

Tags: battery

The problem started when a new motor was put in. At first the battery would be dead every month or two. Now the current is 1.5amps all the time, and have to keep a charger on it, or jump start it, if not, in the morning. I have pulled every fuse with no change. There is nothing I can find that gets hot, since this is about 20 watts of heat. The car mechanic, that put in the new engine, tested every thing he could, and everything checked out fine. How do I find the parasitic leak?

Comment: With all the electronics on newer vehicles you need to turn off the car and let it sit for 30-45 minutes before testing. Did you check the fuses in the fuse box located on the inside of the vehicle located under the driver's side dashboard by the door?  Do you have any aftermarket electronics? You might want to try unbolting the leads to your alternator in the event the diode is bad.

Comment: Do you have a wiring diagram for the car?

Comment: Do you have more than 1 fuse box in the car?  If you pulled everything out of the fuse box and there was no change, then it sounds like the current draw is from an unfused circuit.  Something could be connected to the battery, starter post, or alternator post and powering this parasitic draw.

Comment: I will get a diagram if I can. there is only 1 fuse box in the interior.  The diode is interesting, I will look into it, getting at it is not easy.